# Is there a way to change your name displayed by git above authored pieces of code in intellij? I accidentally used my password

Tags: git, intellij-idea

[I censored my pw and part of my username. Does anyone know how to change the part in the <>?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVepV.png)

Comment: Cancelling last commit, then commit again using correct identity ?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the command line and typing:

```
$ git config --global user.email "johndoe@cool.edu"
```

If I recall correctly the name in the brackets(<>) is the email and the name outside is the user.name field.

You can also look at the output of this command:

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
```

and search your password, then change the variable in question with the above command.

Sources/Tutorials:

- https://www.atlassian.com/en/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup